# How to sort two or three arrays at the same time?

Tags: c++, c++17

I saw in C ++ 17 an interesting way to sort, I want to recreate it using only arrays

There is a way how to parse the map array into 2 elements, I want to implement this using only regular arrays.

```
for (auto&& [key, value] : map)
    {

        cout << key << "\n" << endl;

        cout << value << "\n" << endl;

    }
```

I am trying to repeat the implementation using two arrays, then I will try to add 3 arrays, etc.

```
int64_t arr[2][4]
    {
        { 1,2,3,4 },
        { 2,3,1,0 }
    };

    for (auto&& [a, b] : arr[0], arr[1])
    {

        cout << b << "\n" << endl;

        cout << a << "\n" << endl;

    }
```

Perhaps this is stupid, because the size of the arrays are the same and you can simply specify how many cycles to repeat.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[0][i] << "\n" << endl;

        cout << arr[1][i] << "\n" << endl;
    }
```

But my experiment was created in an attempt to speed up the code.

The question is, can I do this somehow and will it work faster?

```
for (auto&& [a, b] : arr[0], arr[1])
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're trying to do (or what it has to do with sorting) but you might want to look at [`boost::zip_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html).

Comment: The question is misleading. You are only iterating the arrays. No sorting involved at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be easy in C++20 with the addition of ranges, but in the meantime there's the standalone library version [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/view/zip.hpp>

int main() {
  int arr[2][4]{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 1, 0}};

  for (const auto [a, b] : ranges::views::zip(arr[0], arr[1])) {
    std::cout << a << '\t' << b << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Irange-v3/include ziptest.cpp
$ ./a.out                                                        
1   2
2   3
3   1
4   0
```

Comment: I like it how can I connect this library?

Comment: @badbi It's a header only library so it's easy to install. Usually you'd just clone the git repo. See https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/ for details